# Proof check: proving that $f$ being uniformly continuous implies $f$ bounded

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$. Show that $f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

Can I have help checking my specific proof? I'm self-studying and have no grader.

---

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous and suppose there exists a sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $|f(x_n)|\to\infty$, with $x_n\in(a,b)$ for all $n$ and $x\in[a,b]$. In particular, for all fixed $n\geq0$, we have $\lim_{m\to\infty}|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|=\infty$. We will show a contradiction.

Let $\epsilon>0$. By uniform continuity, $\exists\delta>0$ such that, $\forall x,y\in(a,b)$, we have $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. By convergence, we also have that $\exists N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $|x_n-x|<\delta/2$. Then $\forall n,m>N$ we have $|x_n-x_m|\leq|x_n-x|+|x_m-x|<\delta$. But then, fixing some $n>N$, we have for all $m>N$ that $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|<\epsilon$. In particular:
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\leq\epsilon,$$
which concludes the proof.

Comment: "By convergence, we also have that ..." What if $x_n$ does not converge to any $x\in (a,b)$? (That is, what if $x_n\to a$ or $x_n\to b$?)

Comment: I don't think I use $x\in(a,b)$ in any part of the proof, only that $x_n,x_m\in(a,b)$ so that I can apply uniform continuity.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I see the issue now. Pretty sure this edit will patch it up? Thanks for the help.

Comment: A function can be unbounded on $(a,b)$ without having a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to a limit in $(a,b)$ with $|f(x_n)| \to \infty$. A simple example would be $f(x) = 1/x$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Bungo Right, but I let $x_n$ converge to $x\in[a,b]$, and I don't use $x$ itself in any part of the proof that invokes uniform continuity on $(a,b)$. That I know of, anyways.

Comment: Oops, I misread $x \in [a,b]$ as $x \in (a,b)$. Your proof may be OK, but you need to argue why such a sequence $(x_n)$ is guaranteed to exist if we assume that $f$ is unbounded. Is this a consequence of unboundedness only, or of unboundedness together with uniform continuity? It's not clear.

Comment: Once you clear this up, you should consider trying to prove this constructively as an exercise.

Comment: OK, so $(x_n)$ exists so that $|f(x_n)|\to\infty$ I think is just unboundedness stated in terms of a sequence. If no such $(x_n)$ existed then $f$ wouldn't be unbounded. To show that it converges, we note that $[a,b]$ is compact and thus some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges in $[a,b]$ to a point--we'll call it $x$. We'll just pick this sequence as our $(x_n)$. And we're still given that $f(x_n)\to\infty$. Does this plug the hole or did I miss the issue?

Comment: Yep, that works. The key is the sequential compactness of $[a,b]$.